# Using class method as callback in Python

Tags: python, class, callback, self

I have one class with constructor that recieve two functions as callback's.

```py
class TreeTraverse:
    def __init__(self, branch_head: Node, node_processor: Callable[[Phrase], None], ascent: Callable[[], None]):
        self._branch_head: Node = branch_head
        self._ascent: Callable[[], None] = ascent
        self._node_processor: Callable[[Phrase], None] = node_processor
        ...
```

I annotated parameters using typing module: one of them should recieve 1 parameter, other - without parameters. Then I have another class which passes their methods as callbacks:

```py
class CodeGenerator:
    def phrase_processor(self, phrase: Phrase):
        pass

    def asc(self):
        pass

    def generate(self):
        tree_traverse = TreeTraverse(self._tree.get_head(), node_processor=self.phrase_processor, ascent=self.asc)
        tree_traverse.traverse()
```

---

The question is why this code works? Is it allowed to be left as is?

Class method has extra "self" argument at the first position. And at the place where function called I should pass class instance to this method. But appears that is not required.

My guess is that the all in python is object (including functions and methods), and this object has a stash, where self is put when I pass method.

Comment: You're mostly right - "why does it works" is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) and [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod). Note that in Python's terms,  `phrase_processor` is an "instance method", not a "class method".

Comment: Well, yes, everything is an object, including functions. But look, is this any more surprising than the fact that you don't have to do `instance.method(instance)` and can just do `instance.method()`? Essentially, any time a function that is in a class namespace is accessed through an instance of that class, the function gets "magically" bound with the instance as the first object. The "magic" is that function objects are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and `__get__` will essentially partially apply the instance to itself and return that function instead.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers nice wiki article, unsung hero indeed! but maybe it should be updated for Python 3 :)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers is it good practice to use methods as callback?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thx ;-) But you should mainly thanks John Posner for publishing it first (this was actually something I posted on comp.lang.python). And yes, I thought about updating it for Python3, but OTHO this now quite clearly explained in the doc.

Comment: @pilot yes of course, why ? This is even quite standard in GUI programming. You can pass just any callable (function, method, class, custom callable...) as long as it has the expected signature.